# 'invalid operands to binary operands' while comparing two unions

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linked-list, binary-operators

I am writing a code for implementing linked list in C that is type agnostic. This is what I am trying to do.

1. Create a union that can store either of these: int, char*, double, char.

   `union element { int num; char* str; double real; char alph; };`
2. An enum to keep track of what element the union is storing.

   `enum { NUM, STR, REAL, CHAR };`
3. A struct that will store the node values.

   `struct node { int type; union element data; struct node *next; };`
4. Since I might have more than one list, I am also creating a container for the node as,

   `struct list { struct node *head; };`

Now I want to create a funtion that will fetch a element from the list. The function is,

```
node* findkey(list *l, union element key)
{
    node *i=list->head;
    while(!i) {
        if(i->data == key) {
            return i;
        i=i->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

When I compile the code, `clang` throws me this error,

```
linkedlist.c:33:11: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('union element' and
      'union element')
                if(i->data == key)
                   ~~~~ ^  ~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You can't compare unions like that.

Comment: @Shawn How can I compare two unions then?

Comment: C does not permit comparison of unions in the absence of any other information.  The reason is that a C union does not carry any meta-data to state which element is currently "active".  So you'd need to pass not only the union but the type `enum` as well to your `findkey` routine.  Then when iterating down the list, you'd compare the two types first, and only if they match compare the corresponding members of the two unions.

Comment: If you have two unions that both hold values of the the same type, you can compare those values like you normally would values of that type.

Comment: @dgnuff How can I do that? Like, if I add something like `if(i->type==keytype && i->data==key)` (`keytype` is a enum that is passed through the function), how does the compiler know that check in the first part has anything to do with the union?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moved this to an answer since it's no longer comment appropriate.

The root cause of the problem is that if the union member are different sizes, you are not guaranteed that the comparison will succeed if write to smaller members but then compare  larger members.  For example, if you wrote to the `alph` member of both unions, but then compare the `num` members, the one byte that holds `alph` will compare correctly, but even if they're equal, the remaining bytes in `num` may be different, leading to a "false unequal" result.  Same with writing to the `num` members and then comparing the `real` members.

So to avoid this problem, you need to first compare the two `type` values, and only if they match compare the appropriate pair of union members.  The selection of which members to compare can most easily be done with a switch.

```
node* findkey(list *l, union element key, int type)
{
    node *i=list->head;
    while(!i) {
        // compare types first, assume no match if they differ
        if(i->type != type) {
            continue
        }
        switch (type)
        {
        case NUM:
            if(i->data.num == key.num) {
                return i;
            }
            break;
        case STR:
            ...
        case REAL:
            ...
        case CHAR:
            ...
        }
        i=i->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I'll add a note that how you handle `case STR:` is dependant on the behavior you want.  If you want the two stings to match, use `strcmp()` if you want them to refer to the same string, use `==` on the two pointers.  I suspect that the former will be a more useful way to do things, but it's worth noting the exact pointer comparison.  Somewhat akin to the difference between `==` and `===` in PHP.

Comment: well, it is not undefined behaviour any more to read other members of the union, they will "reinterpret" the bytes written to them

Comment: TYVM for explaining the downvote.  Post has been edited to reflect the fact that it's not UB in C, but that it is still error prone due to size differences.  If you find this edit acceptable please consider removing the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
if(i->data == key) {
```

its comparing union variable which is invalid as told in [Harbison and Steele book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013089592X)

> **Structures** and **unions** cannot be compared for **equality**, even though
>   assignment for these types is allowed. The gaps in structures and
>   unions caused by alignment restrictions could contain arbitrary
>   values, and compensating for this would impose an unacceptable
>   overhead on the equality comparison or on all operations that modified
>   structure and union types.

you can compare union members like

```
if(i->data.num == key.num) {
 /*  some code */    
}
```